# Ordering of asynchronous javascript events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
$("#submit_financials").live('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    // using serialize here to pass the POST variables to the django view function
    var serialized_data = $("#financials_filter_form").serialize()

    $.post("/ajax/custom_filter/", serialized_data, function(response){
        // create a graph
    });
    $.post("/ajax/force_download/", serialized_data, function(response){
        alert('hello');
    });

});
```

However, when I do this code, I get the response 'hello' **before** the graph. Why is this happening? And how would I change this such that I get the graph first?

Comment: JavaScript is not a synchronous language; use callbacks

Comment: javascript *will* do things in a particular order, but AJAX, by definition is asynchronous.

Comment: @RustyTheBoyRobot. This so not true! **javascript is a synchronous language only!**

Comment: @RustyTheBoyRobot that's a really inaccurate statement. Javascript IS a completely synchronous language, but AJAX calls are not.

Comment: The simple answer is that both requests get fired one right after the other and run concurrently; `custom_filter` seems to take longer to process on the server so that `force_download` returns first and invokes your callback.

Comment: @all - Thanks for the corrections; my mistake. Ajax != JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Async, you can never know which function runs\ finish first...

Think on async operations like telling a group of people to run 1 mile, do you know who will finish first? (Yes, Jon skeet, then Chuck Norris...)

You can use the a callack to run the second ajax:

```
$.post("/ajax/custom_filter/", serialized_data, function(response) {
    // create a graph
    ...
    ...

    $.post("/ajax/force_download/", serialized_data, function(response) {
        alert('hello');
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try using deferred objects **If you want to generate graph before alert but want both calls to be completed**.

```
$.when (
   $.post("/ajax/custom_filter/", serialized_data),
   $.post("/ajax/force_download/", serialized_data)
).done(function(a1,  a2){
    /* a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the 
    custom_filter and force_download post requests  */
   var customFilterResponse = a1[2]; 
   /* arguments are [ "success", statusText, jqXHR ] */

   //generate graph.

   alert('hello');
});
```

Comment: and here I was about to post an answer implementing this manually. Somehow never knew about `$.when()`. Thanks!

Comment: Few hours ago, I was feeling like I'm a truly jQuery Ninja, since I read this answer about `$.when(...)` and I felt like _what is that?_

Comment: +1 Deferred is definitely the way to go if the two requests don't depend on each other but both need to be done before performing some action.

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo Well I am still learning too and this `[ "success", statusText, jqXHR ]` stuff is new and learned it while reading the docs >.<

Comment: @KevinB. Doesn't it work only for animations?! I see 3 upvotes, but I'm almost sure it's wrong. Is it me who is wrong?

Comment: @gdoron - Deferred objects definitely work with ajax requests. Heck, the deferred framework in jQuery was originally written FOR ajax requests. (it was included in jQuery 1.5 with the jQuery.ajax rewrite)

Comment: @KevinB. I'm sure I tried it once, and it didn't work for me... Let me try it. But how jQuery knows when the ajax request completed?

Comment: @gdoron - $.ajax doesn't implement a true deferred object, it simply implements an interface that mimics it enough to be used as a deferred object iirc(i'd have to dig into the core). It has a .done, .fail, .always, .then, and a .promise method that returns an object that has those same five methods (maybe more).

Comment: @gdoron If you thumb through the core, it creates a deferred object and applies it to the jqXHR object, then maps the success error and complete callbacks to the .done .fail and .always deferred callbacks. I didn't know you could simply apply a deferred object to an existing object that way. Interesting!

Comment: @KevinB The above syntax is documented http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/ Also there is a deprecation notice on recommending to use deferred callbacks. _Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead._

Comment: +1 for learning something new, (I'm almost sure I tried it once with no luck...)

Answer (score 0):

option 1 is to nest the post requests (gdoron's response). If this is not possible/practical, you can use a mutually scoped variable as a flag (change value in the response callback functions and then use setTimeout and recursion (or setInterval) to keep looking for a change in your "flag" variable and when you see it change, then pop the next $.post request